# Change lockscreen wallpaper on Xfce Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux, xfce, lock-screen

After a lot of failures while searching for a solution in the net I am setting this again, this time for Kali 2020.1 release.

I have tried:

- Changing the images path referred in

  ```
  /usr/share/images/desktop-base/desktop-lockscreen.xml
  ```

  to the desired. There wasn't any change after rebooting.
- Changing the images path referred in

  ```
  /usr/share/backgrounds/kali/kali-light.xml
  ```

  to the desired. There wasn't any change after rebooting.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

You may have changed it by now but I'm answering this in case someone else may need it.

**Option 1 - Terminal**

Under `/usr/share/desktop-base/kali-theme/login/` is a symbolic link named `background`. Update it with your desired image path.

Sample Command:
`sudo ln -s <image_path> /usr/share/desktop-base/kali-theme/login/background`

**Option 2 - GUI**

1. Click *Menu* > *Settings* > *LightDM GTK+ Greeter settings*
2. Authenticate if necessary
3. In the *Appearance* tab of the window, select an image/color under *Background*
4. Click *Save*

Reboot to take effect.

Comment: Thanks for answering! No I haven't changed it yet because I didn't find a solution. I will respond as soon as I am able to test it. Again, thank you!!

Comment: GUI option worked for me. CLI option did not...

Comment: CLI works fine, could check below

Answer (score 0):

The CLI works fine for me. Just don't forget to add `-sf` to force it since the file already exist.

```
sudo ln -sf <image_path> /usr/share/desktop-base/kali-theme/login/background
```

[How to change where a symlink points](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151999/how-to-change-where-a-symlink-points)